# How to hide columns in ObjectGears export to Excel?

Tags: objectgears

I am hiding some columns for certain groups of users on ObjectGears Datas page utilizing Script for list of records. This works, however, when users click on downloading the list to Excel the hidden columns are included? Do I need any special command to restrict also columns that are downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new release will contain this feature ensuring columns hidden on the list of records (even by script) will not be included in the Excel download.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue. I turned to Objectgears directly and they confirmed this is a bug in 1.5.0 Objectgears version. The new version should automatically take out from the Excel download also the columns hidden by script on Datas page. So the both datasets will match.